# Is it an example of a stack based buffer overflow when characters written into one local array appear in another local array

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to trigger a buffer overflow by using the below code in order to understand the vulnerability better.

I have certain fields, some have a width specified to try to prevent the overflow, but I left that out in one case (firstName) to leave the overflow possible:

```
char firstName[21], surName[31], job[16];

printf("Enter first name: ");
scanf("%s", firstName);
printf("Enter surname: ");
scanf("%30s", surName);
printf("Enter job name : ");
scanf("%15s", job);
```

So now when I input the following:

```
UmbertoTestingOverflow
Example
Janitor
```

The recorded variables show as:

```
UmbertoTestingOverfoExample
Example
Janitor
```

According to my understanding of buffer overflow, the extra characters in firstname should have ran over into another field, but in this case it has taken user input from another variable and added it to first name. So is this buffer overflow behavior or is something else causing this?

Comment: Yes, it's buffer overflow. Notice how surName comes right after firstName in the memory. You can see that happening with the printfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is overflowing buffers on the stack.

The `firstName` input *did* overflow into `surName`.  But you then changed `surName` when you input that, and it overwrote the characters with `Example`.

Because you overflowed `firstName`, there is no null-terminator on the string, so it looks like `firstName` is longer than it actually is.  It then had the "end" of it overwritten (because those bytes belonged to another variable).

This is actually undefined behaviour.  You don't know where the compiler will put your buffers in the stack.

To prevent overflowing your buffers, you should use `fgets` to read strings, not `scanf`:

```
fgets( firstName, 21, stdin );
```

Comment: Shouldn't the scanf method I used prevent overflow by specifying the width like scanf("%30s".....

Comment: Yes, but it's more hidden (and optional) and you have to manually update it if you change your string lengths later (even if using constants).  The safer `scanf_s` was designed to help, but it's clunky.  There's a subtle difference between `scanf` and `fgets` that I didn't mention.  `scanf` will stop reading when it reads a whitespace.  So if I enter "Computer Geek" as a job, it will only give back "Computer" and leave "Geek" in the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is buffer overflow behavior.

Line 4, the firstname `scanf`, did indeed encounter a buffer overflow. It saved the long name beginning at `firstName` and continuing into the space occupied by `surName`.  It concluded with a zero terminator, of course.

Line 6 then **overwrote** the long name with the new surname "Example", starting at `surName`. It also concluded with a zero terminator.

printf of `firstName` then begins at the start of `firstName` and continues, past the end of `firstName` into `surName`, until it finds a zero terminator.

When buffer overflow is used as an exploit, it would generally be where firstName is scanned AFTER surName, so that the overflow it writes will not itself be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you overflowed the first array into the second.

On the first assignment, `firstName` contained `UmbertoTestingOverflo` and the first character of `surName` was set to `w`. On the second assignment, `surName` was set to `Example`.

When you printed `firstName` it kept printing letters until it encountered the `\0` character which was at the end of `surName`. The memory associated with `job` was never altered.